# How does the partial transpose operation look like in matrix form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

The link [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179671/how-to-take-partial-trace) gives a nice description of how partial trace looks in matrix notation. I want a similar explanation for the matrix partial-transposition. How does matrix partial-transposition operation look in the matrix form rather than in Dirac notation?

Comment: Transposition or partial transposition?

Comment: I meant partial transposition. I just corrected it.

Comment: Which of the linked answers you like? The first can be translated 1-to-1 to the transpose.

Comment: I like the second one. Where one can write the action of partial tracing as summing to the basis of one party and leaving the other alone (the identity matrix).

Answer (score 2):

In bra-ket notatoin, if the matrix $M$ reads
$$M=\sum_{ijkl}M_{ij,k\ell} \lvert i,j\rangle\!\langle k,\ell\rvert\equiv \sum_{ijkl}M_{ij,k\ell} (\lvert i\rangle\!\langle k\rvert\otimes\lvert j\rangle\!\langle \ell\rvert),$$
then its partial transpose with respect to the second space is
$$M^{T_B}= \sum_{ijkl}M_{ij,k\ell} (\lvert i\rangle\!\langle k\rvert\otimes\lvert \ell\rangle\!\langle j\rvert).$$

Equivalently, the partial transpose $M^{T_B}$ is that matrix with components
$$\big(M^{T_B}\big)_{ij,k\ell}=M_{i\ell,kj}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The representaion you look for does not exist because partial transposition is not a complete positive map.

Comment: how is this related to the question? A map does not need to be completely positive to admit a "matrix form" (though it's somewhat unclear what is meant with "matrix form" in this context)

Answer (score 1):

An operator $M$ acting on a vector space $V_A \otimes V_B$ can be decomposed as: $M = \sum_{ij} c_{ij} A^{(i)} \otimes B^{(i)}$ with $A^{(i)}$ acting on $V_A$ and $B^{(j)}$ acting on $V_B$. Using matrices to denote $M$, $A^{(i)}$ and $B^{(i)}$:
$$
M 
=
\sum_{ij} c_{ij}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a^{(i)}_{11} B^{(i)} & a^{(i)}_{12} B^{(i)} & \cdots \\
a^{(i)}_{21} B^{(i)} & a^{(i)}_{22} B^{(i)} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then, the partial transpositions are:
$$
M^{T_A}
=
\sum_{ij} c_{ij}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a^{(i)}_{11} B^{(i)} & a^{(i)}_{21} B^{(i)} & \cdots \\
a^{(i)}_{12} B^{(i)} & a^{(i)}_{22} B^{(i)} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}
\right)
\\
M^{T_B}
=
\sum_{ij} c_{ij}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a^{(i)}_{11} (B^{(i)})^T & a^{(i)}_{12} (B^{(i)})^T & \cdots \\
a^{(i)}_{21} (B^{(i)})^T & a^{(i)}_{22} (B^{(i)})^T & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$